# IF / ELSE depending on result of stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckAdminExists]
    @SID NVARCHAR(50),
    @AdminName NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
    SELECT
        Administrator.ID
    FROM
        Administrator
    WHERE
        Administrator.SID = @SID
        AND Administrator.Name = @AdminName
GO
```

Now I would like to create another SP with a code like that:

```
IF NOT NULL (EXECUTE CheckAdminExists 'S-1','Admin')
--do something
ELSE
--do something else
```

What's the right syntax for doing it?

Comment: what is wrong with just doing it inline? like: `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Administrator WHERE Administrator.SID = @SID AND Administrator.Name = @AdminName) BEGIN PRINT 'it exists' END ELSE BEGIN PRINT 'it DOES NOT exists' END`  that is such a trivial query, just include it where you need it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not use a stored procedure for this and use a function instead to check if the Admin Exists.

Then in your new stored procedure call the CheckAdminExists function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CheckAdminExists] (@SID NVARCHAR(50), @AdminName NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS BIT
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @RetVal INT

SELECT @RetVal = COUNT(Administrator.ID)
FROM
    Administrator
WHERE
    Administrator.SID = @SID
    AND Administrator.Name = @AdminName

IF @RetVal > 0 
BEGIN
   RETURN 1
END
    RETURN 0
END

Then in your stored procedure call the function:

DECLARE @AdminExists BIT
SELECT @AdminExists = [dbo].[CheckAdminExists]

IF @AdminExists 
BEGIN
   -- your code 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  -- your code
END
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Darren. The code doesn't work. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CheckAdminExists, Line 8.
In Line: DECLARE @RetVal INT

Comment: COUNT can be way more expensive than an EXISTS

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, use `FUNCTION`.

But if you need to return more than 1, use `OUTPUT` parameters.